# springml spark salesforce - Records not found for this query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, salesforce, aws-glue

I use spark salesforce library com.springml:spark-salesforce_2.11:1.1.3 and it was working, but I started to get errors. It looks like Salesforce returns dataframe with a column "Records not found for this query" and nulls. Do you know how to solve it?

root
|-- Records not found for this query: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------+
|Records not found for this query|
+--------------------------------+
| ActivityId__c|
| null|
| null|
| null|

My code in glue job is:

```
    df = spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce").option("soql",sql).option("sfObject",sf_table).option("bulk","true").option("pkChunking",pkChunking).option("timeout","99999999").option("username", login).option("password",password).load()
```

Comment: I don't see inferSchema option in your code. Could you please include  .option("inferSchema", "true") in your code and print the Schema and see what data type is inherited

Comment: I added "inferSchema", but the result is the same. PrinSchema result:
root
 |-- Records not found for this query: string (nullable = true